# Java Switching between Panels of One Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working in Java desktop application and I'm not familar with JAVA ,I have a problem on switching between panels so when I select an JMenuItem from a JMenu the actual panel should change.
I have a main Jframe and only one Panel ,so how can I add other panels for others JmenuItem, in the same Jframe, I try this code :

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    TextArea ta; 

    Dimension d = mainPanel.getSize();  
    mainPanel.removeAll();        
    JPanel painel3 = new JPanel();  
    painel3.setSize(d);  
    ta = new TextArea();  
    ta.setSize(d);

    painel3.add(ta);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();  
    scrollPane.add(painel3);  
    mainPanel = painel3; 
}
```

Comment: Please check if [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is suitable for your case

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
private void menuItem1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    scrollPane.getViewport().removeAll();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(panel1);
}                                          

private void menuItem2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    scrollPane.getViewport().removeAll();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(panel2);
}
```

The JScrollPane has a "view port" on a generally unbounded plane where you place your JPanel.
So one does not add immediately to the scroll pane. One could do `new JScrollPane(panel3)` however for initialisation.